Simultaneous diagonalization of three positive definite matrices in a general sense
Given a set of three real symmetric positive definite matrices $\{\mathbf{M}_i\}$, does there always exist invertible square matrices $\mathbf{P}, \mathbf{Q}$ such that $\{\mathbf{P}\mathbf{M}_i\mathbf{Q}^T\}$ is a set of diagonal matrices?
There are no requirements on $\mathbf{P}, \mathbf{Q}$ other than invertibility - they do not need to be orthonormal, nor do they need to have any relationship with each other.
If this problem is hard to answer, what about the case where the set is $\{\mathbf{M}, \mathbf{N}, \mathbf{I}\}$?
I am aware of a similar (unanswered) question posted here before, but that is only for the case of two (strictly positive semi-definite) matrices.  The answer to this question is no when $\mathbf{P}, \mathbf{Q}$ are orthonormal (Corollary 9, "Simultaneous Singular Value Decomposition", Maehara and Murota) or when $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{Q}$ (Theorem 7, "Solving the problem of simultaneous diagonalization of complex symmetric matrices via congruence", Bustamante et al.).  There seems to be a theme in all methods of simultaneous diagonalization that, after a certain point, some matrices really have to start commuting for the statement to hold.  I suspect the answer is no for this problem too, but hope that it is not!
Edit: Specified that the set should consist of three matrices, thanks to Adayah's comment!

Is there any constraint on the set ${ M_i }$, or could it simply consist of all real symmetric positive definite matrices?

No constraint - that's a good point that the set could be so large as to make it impossible merely by means of having too many matrices to describe with so few parameters!
I'll limit the case to just three matrices to prevent this, since three is the case I am interested in anyways.

Interestingly, a quick check on the number of parameters implies that, for sets of 5 or more matrices, it is always impossible for sufficiently large matrices.  But for 4 or less, there are always sufficiently many parameters.  (Which makes sense, as P, Q have roughly twice as many parameters each as a symmetric matrix).

No. If $P$ and $Q$ exist, then $PM_iQ^T$ is an invertible diagonal matrix for each $i$. Therefore $PM_iM_j^{-1}P^{-1}=(PM_iQ^T)(PM_jQ^T)^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix. It follows that $M_1M_3^{-1}$ and $M_2M_3^{-1}$ commute. If we take $M_3=I$, this implies that all positive definite matrices commute, which we know is untrue.
